# always clicks first menu item after hover

Tags: webdriver

I have a menu that is only visible after a mouse hover. The mouse hover works and the menu becomes visible for a moment. An attempted click action always clicks the first item in the menu. I want to command it to click any item in the list. I am currently using the id to find.

```
IWebElement settingsMenu = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ctl00_Main_Header_SettingsMenu"));
var actionbuilder = new Actions(_driver);
actionbuilder.MoveToElement(settingsMenu);
actionbuilder.Perform(); //perform menu hover, this always works
//menu items now visible
IWebElement ScheduleSettings = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ctl00_Main_Header_lnkSchedulingSettings"));
actionbuilder.MoveToElement(ScheduleSettings);
actionbuilder.Perform();
ScheduleSettings.Click();
```

The ScheduleSettings is the second item in the menu from top to bottom. The first item always gets clicked.

Comment: I want to add that even though a mouse hover happens, it does not persist. With a real mouse hover the menu stays open until something else happens. I am now noticing that sometimes no menu item is being clicked at all.

Comment: mouse hover is working to expand the menu, but it is not working at all for any of the menu items.

Answer (score 0):

use this when you are building your driver

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capabilities.setCapability("enablePersistentHover", false);
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
```